# actionscript, drag and drop an object from a list of objects

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm creating an application where the user can select an object from a list of objects, and then put it on the main window.

I want to have the list of objects presented like in the web app : 
http://builds.balsamiq.com/b/mockups-web-demo/

The user can select a category, then the list of objects of that category is displayed, then he can drag and drop an object to the main window.

How is it possible to do this, having a list of objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should write a class for every list of objects, add your items in your class and then write your drag and drop function for that class.

```
public class DragDrop extends MovieClip
{
    public function DragDrop()
    {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    }

    private function drag(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.startDrag();
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,drop);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how to display them like in the example http://builds.balsamiq.com/b/mockups-web-demo/ ?? 

store them in categories and displaying a list of them, like a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Coordy is a nice little toolkit for constructing and keeping track of things laid out in lists:

http://somerandomdude.com/projects/coordy/

The main examples are for 3D spiral layouts and such, but Coordy works well for simpler linear layouts too.